# Send request parameters from JSON with PUT request using Meteor.http.call()

Tags: javascript, json, rest, meteor

Code below:

```
    function getAddress() {
          var kite = Meteor.npmRequire('coinkite-javascript'); 
          sign = kite.auth_headers('somekey', 'somesecret', '/v1/new/receive');
          console.log(kite.auth_headers('somekey', 'somesecret', '/v1/new/receive'));
          console.log(Meteor.http.call("PUT", "https://api.coinkite.com/v1/new/receive", { params: { account: 'CA8A4C1B40-359DC0' } + sign}));
        };
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        getAddress();

    });
```

Anyhow, this code is not working for some reason. 
While the JSON object returned by the key generator (sign) is:

{ 'X-CK-Key': 'somekey','X-CK-Sign': '3655960c6ad67a0f3d57cd9468d375defcdae96587e6b5778e6dbbb9b6470568',
'X-CK-Timestamp': '2015-05-12T01:09:55.551Z' }

the request returns a 401 saying the X-CK-KEY is not defined.

How can I effectively add these parameters to the put request?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call), shouldn't you send your authentication headers in the `headers` option?

```
function getAddress() {
      var kite = Meteor.npmRequire('coinkite-javascript'); 
      sign = kite.auth_headers('somekey', 'somesecret', '/v1/new/receive');
      console.log(kite.auth_headers('somekey', 'somesecret', '/v1/new/receive'));
      console.log(Meteor.http.call("PUT", "https://api.coinkite.com/v1/new/receive", { params: { account: 'CA8A4C1B40-359DC0' }, headers: sign}));
    };
Meteor.startup(function () {
    getAddress();

});
```